# Problems with NULL or EMPTY variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to code a very simple php single line if statement but am having problems with a null result. If companyname is NULL then use the firstname + lastname combo.

```
SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `companyname` FROM (`client`) WHERE `client_id` = '116'

Array
(
    [firstname] => John
    [lastname] => Citizen
    [companyname] => 
)

$name = trim($row['companyname']) == FALSE ? $row['firstname'] & " " & $row['lastname'] : $row['companyname'] ;
```

I have tried all the following options to no avail;

- empty
- == FALSE
- === NULL

but none of them will return me the firstname + lastname combo that I'm expecting.

Comment: you could use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in your SQL to return a particular string you can check when companyname is NULL. ie `COALESCE(companyname ,"<EMPTY>")` then you can do `$row['companyname'] == "<EMPTY>"` in PHP.

Comment: Not sure where you got this: `$row['firstname'] & " " & $row['lastname']`, but that should be `$row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname']` - that will cause all sorts of issues!

Comment: Did you try `== ""`?

Comment: Why not just do this in steps, using if and else statements, as oppose to jumbling them around all in one statement? That's very messy, and as a beginner, I advice you to not use it, if you do not understand it very well.

Comment: If any of these answers helped, it is good form to upvote those that helped and accept the answer that was most helpful / correct.

Comment: Thanks heaps guys for your assistance. The ampersands were a throwback to VB days and I completely missed them. That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `empty` function. If `$row['companyname']` is empty then return the concatenated string of `$row['firstname']` and `$row['lastname']` otherwize return the trimmed value of `$row['companyname']`.

```
$name = ( empty(trim($row['companyname'])) ? ($row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname']) : trim($row['companyname']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple matter in PHP. Instead of `=== FALSE`, why not use a slightly looser typing, and just use the `!` not comparison:

```
$name = ( ! trim($row['companyname']) )
    ? $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] 
    : $row['companyname'];
```

Also - in [PHP you concatenate strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) with `.`, not with `&`....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with 'empty()' like:

```
$name = (empty(trim($row['companyname'])) == TRUE ? $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] : $row['companyname']) ;
```

Comment: You have to use dot and not ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$name = ($row['companyname']=='' )
? $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] 
: $row['companyname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.3, [you can leave out the "middle" statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) when using the ternary operator. Since [an empty string equals boolean false](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), this simple statement works:

```
$name = $row["companyname"] ?: "$row[firstname] $row[lastname]"
```

Also note that if you're concatenating strings (which isn't necessary here) you use `.` and not `&`.